# When does std::vector's storage automatically contract?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, stdvector

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector says:

> The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded **and contracted as needed**.

But I can't find a case where contraction would happen "as needed". None of the shrinking operations contract std::vector's capacity:

[clear()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear):

> Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged

[resize()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

> Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size because that would invalidate all iterators

[erase()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

This implies that iterators and references before the point of the erase don't get invalidated, which would not be the case if the capacity changed.

[pop_back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back):

> Iterators and references to the last element, as well as the end() iterator, are invalidated.

The same applies here.

[shrink_to_fit()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) *does* contract the std::vector, but it was added in C++11 and the sentence above ("and contracted") isn't marked as only applying to C++11 and up. Also, an explicit call to shrink_to_fit() is not automatic ("The storage of the vector is handled automatically") and doesn't happen "as needed".

So when does std::vector automatically contract its storage?

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` doesn't necessarily shrink the capacity to the size: it requests the vector to do so. It's up to the implementation to decide whether to fulfill this request.

Comment: If you want to shrink an empty vector back to 0 capacity, then swapping with a temporary vector will do this. eg `std::vector<int>{}.swap(my_vector);`

Comment: Maybe you could remove "and contracted" from that cppreference page (it is a wiki), indeed.

Comment: @paolo True.  I reckon most implementations will honour the request though, otherwise there's not much point in having that function in the first place.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` has some freedom, because it might not be possible to shrink to the *exact* size. For example, a `std::vector<char>` of size 1 might keep more than 1 byte.

Comment: `swap`. Before c++11, I used that to let OS free the memory. i.e. swap my vector with a temporary empty vector. Take an elegant example from @RichardCritten int the above comment. `std::vector<int>{}.swap(my_vector);`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code of the [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01115_source.html), i didn't find any situation where the memory is freed.

It looks like the standard opens the door to complex memory management implementation but the widely known ones chose to never do that.

Comment: That source code is for GCC 4.6.3, which was released 9 years ago. The sources for GCC 12.2.0 can be found [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/debug/vector). _M_guaranteed_capacity is only shrunk in shrink_to_fit() and swap().